# Unwanted Checkbox selections in RecyclerView in Kotlin (Android)

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, kotlin

In my app I have a RecyclerView which contains 15 static items consisting of a TextView and a CheckBox:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

On click on the item, the according checkbox is set to checked and the item is added to a selection-list.

**The problem**:
When I scroll down and select an item, scroll up again I alwys see another checkbox checked. While debugging I noticed, that only my actually selected item has been added to the list, but nethertheless its a bad user experience when other items are checked/"selected" in the UI randomly.

How can I stop this strange behaviour?

I am using a view holder to manage the item views:

```
private inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
            val checkBox: CheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)
            val text: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text)

            init {
                view.setOnClickListener { checkBox.isChecked = !checkBox.isChecked }
                checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                    val itemText = dataset[adapterPosition]
                    logger.debug("state change $isChecked for $itemText")
                    if (isChecked) selectedItems.add(itemText)
                    else {
                        if (selectedItems.contains(itemText)) selectedItems.remove(itemText)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My onBindViewHolder()-method contains the following:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder?, position: Int) {
            val itemText = dataset[position]
            holder?.text?.text = itemText
        }
```

Comment: This is happening probably because RecylerView recycling logic. When you scroll up, a view that disappears to the bottom is added to the top. In your case: the view with a checked checkbox is recycled (bound) to be used at another spot, which is not what you want. This can be fixed using the onBindViewHolder call, and decorating the UI according to the data state at every bind. Mind sharing what logic you have there?

Comment: @MehmetKologu is right. Your 'onBindViewHolder' mechanics should make sure you set the proper text and checked state to your CheckBox. If you could post your implementation there it would be helpful. Also as a side note, on your last line checking `if (selectedItems.contains(itemText))` is rather redundant. You could just call `selectedItems.remove(itemText)`. It does nothig if the item is not contained.

Comment: Thank you for clarification @Mehmet. I added my onBindViewHolder-snippet to the bottom of my post

Comment: just add a line to your onBind method to set the checkbox value. This should look like this : `itemText holder?.checkBox?.setChecked(selectedItems.contains(dataset[‌​position]))`. Hope this helps

Comment: In your onBindViewHolder, you're setting the text to the correct one. You also need to set the state of the checkBox the same way. It might mean re-thinking what your dataset contains, or going through your selectedItems to decide if you need to check the checkBox for the current item or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably happening because of the RecyclerView recycling logic. When you scroll up, a view that disappears to the bottom is added to the top. In your case: the view with a checked checkbox is recycled (bound) to be used at another spot, which is not what you want. To fix this you need to keep tracked of what views should have a checked checkbox. Only change the state of the checkbox in a view depending on the data state associated with that view. Since you're already keeping track of items that should be checked in the `selectedItems` array, just add the following code to `onBindViewHolder`.

`holder?.checkbox?.isChecked = selectedItems.contains(itemText)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this worked for me

Declare a **boolean** field in your data modal class with other useful fields

```
 public boolean isIs_selected() {
        return is_selected;
    }

    public void setIs_selected(boolean is_selected) {
        this.is_selected = is_selected;
    }

    boolean is_selected = false;
```

then in adapter class do this
in `MyViewHolder` class

```
private inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

            init {
              val checkBox: CheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)
              val text: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text)
            }
        }
```

then finally in `onBindViewHolder` method do this

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {     
            //in some cases, it will prevent unwanted situations
            holder. checkbox!!.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

            //if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected
            holder. checkbox!!.setChecked(array.get(position).isIs_selected());

            holder. checkbox!!.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                dataSet.get(holder.adapterPosition).isIs_selected=isChecked

            }
        }
```